# How to show tooltip only if a region is clicked in jVectorMap, and let it open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm using this [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/usa/). By default, it shows tooltip on hover.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve -

1. Show tooltip only **on click** *(partially working but tooltip should be be above the mouse cursor. I couldn't figure out how to get mouse cursor position.)*
2. Let the tooltip opens until user explicitly clicks on **close**.

Code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufhz316z/)

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
    map: "us_aea_en",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: "#818486"
        }
    },
    onRegionClick: function (e, code) {
        var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');        
        map.tip.show();
        map.tip.html(code + "<p>Click to Close</p>");
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function (e, tip, code) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**Desire Behavior**

[image]

Comment: You should start off noting that the default functionality is to modify the tooltip contents on each hover.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it working the way you want and updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inanda/ufhz316z/5/

**Javascript**

```
 $('#map').vectorMap({
    map: "us_aea_en",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    regionsSelectable: true,
    regionsSelectableOne: true,
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: "#818486"
        },
        selected: {
            fill: "#C0C0C0"
      }
    },
    onRegionClick: function (e, code) {
        var map = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
        var customTip=$('#customTip');

        customTip.css({
          left: left,
          top: top
        })

        customTip.html(map.tip.text());
      customTip.show();
      customTip.append(code + "<p>Click to Close</p>");
        customTip.children("p").click(function(){
            map.clearSelectedRegions();
           customTip.hide(); 
        }) 

    },
    onRegionTipShow: function (e, tip, code) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

var left,top;
$('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').container.mousemove(function(e){
   left = e.pageX - 40;
   top = e.pageY - 60;

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="customTip" class="jvectormap-tip"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to highlight the selected state (region)?

Comment: Yes, it is. Take a look at my updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: Cool tip: the `onRegionTipShow` part can be used to prevent the default tooltip display function without messing with any attributes or styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight the selected region via fill or stroke parameters. More details can be found in the documentation of jVectorMap. Here a short example:

```
regionStyle: {
   selected: {
      stroke: '#000',
      "stroke-width": 1.3,
      "stroke-opacity": 1
   }
},
```