# Z-Index positioning for jvectormap tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, jvectormap

I'm using ´jvectormap´ plugin and positioning the `.jvectormap-tip` class accordingly to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290479/4370354)

The problem is, my tooltip have `z-index: 999;` and, although neither my contact form or footer section has it set, my tooltip is going beneath the contact form and above the footer section as shown on the picture below.
I also have tried to add `z-index:1` to the form but did not worked.

What should I do to position the tooltip above anything on the page ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I want just adding a higher `z-index` value for the `tooltip` ancestor( because it haves `relative` position) then the form ancestor.